# How to check only specific s3 bucket exists using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to list a specific bucket in my `aws` account. But I have used `list_buckets()` method which returns all the buckets. Purpose is to check if this **bucket exists or not**

I could have used `head_bucket()` method, but it doesn't return anything in return (according to `boto3` documentation)

I am using **mistral** workflows to get this bucket (still calling `boto3` methtods) not `python`

But somehow, **is there a `boto3` method to check if the `s3` bucket exists or not?**

I need to get the return and compare it accordingly to check if the bucket exists. So if that condition satisfies, it only triggers the next task in `mistral` stackstorm workflow.

In case you need I will put the workflow as well.

```
check_if_exists:
        action: aws_boto3.boto3action
        input:
          action_name: "list_buckets"
          region: <% $.bucket_region %>
          service: "s3"
        publish:
          return_code: <% task(check_if_exists).result.result.Buckets.select($.Name) %>
        on-success:
           - task_one
        on-error:
          - fail
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `head_bucket()` method. This will return 200 OK if the bucket exists and you have necessary permissions to access it. If the bucket does not exist or if you do not have permission, you will get 403 or 404.

Boto3 Documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.head_bucket

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the `get_bucket_*()` operations, such as [`get_bucket_location()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_location).

However, this will only function correctly if you have permission to run this operation on the bucket and if the bucket belongs to the same account as your IAM credentials.

Comment: assume I have all the permissions (for reading), are there other ways?

Comment: And the other thing is, if it doesn't exist, it give no bucket found error as well. Only way is that `head_bucket` method. In documentation it says, it returns `200` if exists. But again it says it doesn't return anything. Any idea on this?

Comment: It is a `200` response, meaning the web request succeeds. If you try it with a bucket that doesn't exist, it will be a `400` response, which means the web request fails. However, it is likely that the software you are using will interpret this as a failure to make the request, rather than a negative response. That is why I am recommend a command that will return a `200` in both situations.

Comment: Yes. These are `mistral` workflows and that is how it interprets an error.